# Lazy Load issue with Safari & Wkwebview

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I am developing an IOS application but the following code of loading items dynamically doesn't seems to work

```
var offset_c = 5;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var content = document.getElementById("wrap");
            var content_height = content.offsetHeight;
            var yoffset = window.pageYOffset;
            var scrolloffset = yoffset + window.innerHeight;
            if(scrolloffset >= content_height){     
                    $.post("ajax/products_ajax.php?offset",{offset:offset_c},function(data){
                        $(".products").append(data);
                        offset_c = offset_c + 5;
                        });            
                } 
    });
```

What the above code does is , it sends the ajax request fine but it loads the next 10 products(5-15) around 5 times repeatedly . Not really getting the problem with the code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `$.post()` code gets triggered on scroll. This means when a user scrolls (or swipes) in your website/app it will get fired continuously. That's why it gets triggered 5 or more times repeatedly. You should "debounce" the scroll handler, to make sure it doesn't keep on calling. The current code is also a huge hit on performance. On the [David Walsh blog](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) is a nice piece of debounce code:

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

This would look something like this in your example:

```
var efficientScrollHandler = debounce(function() {
  // All the taxing stuff you do
  // Like $.post() and stuff
}, 250); // <-- gets triggered maximum one time per 250ms

$(window).scroll(efficientScrollHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you so much . That makes pure sense and worked amazingly .